# File delete not working - it is only working one time that after restarting Jboss server and in debug mode

Tags: java, jsp, jboss, jakarta-ee

I am developing a System using `Struts 1.x`, `Jsp` `Servlet` and `Pentaho`(report generation).

Here when after generating report user can open and save that file as excel and that is working fine.

But problem occurs when a open a file, it creates file in our jboss temp folder that file is not deleted - that is the  issue.

we are deleting file from code level and we figureout that after restating sever after first time it is deleting and other thing is when debugging it is deleting every time.

```
public Object process() throws RenderException, IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    // properties for XSSF
    File xmlFile = null;
    File templateFile = null;
    Writer xmlWriter = null;
    boolean isXLSX = false;
    timeStamp = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

    try {
        OutputType outputType = rendererAttrList.getOutputType();

        Frame[] frameList = xmlDef.getShownFrames(renderDocs);
        if (frameList != null) {
            // ==============================================TPID#65448 code
            // add========================================
            boolean isPentahoExcel = false;
            Frame t_CurrFrame = frameList[0];

            if (t_CurrFrame != null) {

                FrameType frameType = t_CurrFrame.getFrameType();
                if (frameType == FrameType.FRAME_TYPE_EXTERNAL) {
                    isPentahoExcel = true;
                }
            }
            // ==============================================TPID#65448 code end========================================

            isXLSX = isXLSXOutput(frameList);

            // native excel support and if the output is not supported by
            // .xls, change the output to .xlsx
            if (((outputType == OutputType.NATIVE_EXCEL2007) || ((outputType == OutputType.NATIVE_EXCEL97) && isXLSX))&&!isPentahoExcel)
                     {
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
                rendererAttrList.setOutputType(OutputType.NATIVE_EXCEL2007);

                xmlFile = File.createTempFile(getXmlDef().getName()
                        + timeStamp, ".xml");

                logger.info("XML File location :"
                        + xmlFile.getAbsolutePath());

                xmlWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(
                        xmlFile), "UTF-8");
                spreadSheetWriter = new SpreadsheetWriter(xmlWriter);

                spreadSheetWriter.beginSheet();
            } else {
                workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            }


                dataFormat = workbook.createDataFormat();
                sheet = workbook.createSheet("Report");
                logger.debug("Start rendering the excel output in "
                        + rendererAttrList.getOutputType() + " format ");
                renderOutput();
                logger.debug("Stop rendering the excel output ");

            if (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
                // ==============================================TPID#65448 code add========================================

                if (isPentahoExcel) {

                    renderExternalXLSX(t_CurrFrame,byteArrayOutputStream);


                } else {
                    autoSizeColumn();
                    // write the excel to output
                    workbook.write(byteArrayOutputStream);
                }

                // ==============================================TPID#65448 code end========================================
            } else {
                // 1. generate data in XML format
                spreadSheetWriter.endSheet();

                // close the xml stream before we substitute in xlsx file
                try {
                    if (xmlWriter != null)
                        xmlWriter.close();

                    xmlWriter = null;
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    logger.error("Error while closing xmlWriter for file "
                            + xmlFile.getName());
                }

                // Step 2. create template from the excel workbook
                String sheetRef = ((XSSFSheet) sheet).getPackagePart()
                        .getPartName().getName();
                templateFile = createTemplate();

                ByteArrayOutputStream xlsxOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                // Step 3. Substitute the template entry with the generated
                // data
                substitute(templateFile, xmlFile, sheetRef.substring(1),
                        xlsxOutput);

                // if the data is too large don't try to auto size the
                // columns
                // may result into out of memory exception
                if (!isXLSX) {
                    // autosize the columns
                    InputStream inp = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                            xlsxOutput.toByteArray());

                    workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
                    sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                    autoSizeColumn();

                    if (xlsxOutput != null)
                        xlsxOutput.close();

                    byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                    workbook.write(byteArrayOutputStream);
                    inp.close();
                    xlsxOutput.close();
                } else {
                    byteArrayOutputStream = xlsxOutput;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception de) {
        logger.error(de.getMessage(), de);

        throw new RenderException(de.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {


            if (xmlWriter != null)
                xmlWriter.close();

            if (xmlFile != null)
                xmlFile.delete();

            if (templateFile != null){

                    templateFile.delete();                                                      

            }




        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Error while closing xmlWriter for file "
                    + xmlFile.getName());
        }
    }

    return byteArrayOutputStream;
}
```

**Summary of my question -** when `Jboss` restarting then first time and when debugging, temporary created file(temp directory) is deleting successfully .

but when it run normally it not deleting the file

but every time it is calling particular code level problem is why it doesn't perform.

```
templateFile.delete();
```

Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

What happens when the `delete` method is called? You can log the output of the 'delete' method to see the result. It should be `true` or `false`. 
Does it throw an exception? The delete method could throw a `SecurityException` indicating that you are denied access to delete the file.

In general, the first thing to do is try to understand why the file is not beeing deleted given the toolbox provided to you by this particular function.

Another approach could be to also call the deleteIfExists method instead. See here: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#deleteIfExists-java.nio.file.Path-

Comment: Hi ,I tried deleteIfExists() but it didn't work.and i check what happen when we call delete() methods.it is pass false.i cant believe that  when i am debugging it pass true and fill is delting.why is that? thank you very much you help

Comment: @user2991030 - and you don't see any Java Exception in server logs?